# Is it more common to have a heavier maximum bench or squatting weight?

Tags: weightlifting, barbell

For barbell exercises, can most people lift heavier weights when benching or squatting?

Comment: Just because a question is answered somewhere else does not make it a duplicate. That is a different question that just happens to answer this one, so this one should stay open. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For trained lifters, the squat should generally be significantly higher than the bench: Compare “full meet squat” and “full meet bench” at [open powerlifting records](https://www.openpowerlifting.org/records).

That being said, there are certainly bench specialists that bench more than they squat. On the other end of the spectrum, beginners not-infrequently have higher bench presses, as the squat is somewhat more technical and can take longer to develop proficiency in.